# How to determine the last time a user interacted with the matlab GUI?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

In a Matlab function, I would like to know the last time a user interacted with the Matlab GUI.  By matlab GUI, I mean basically, a user typing in the command window, or in the editor.

The algorithm I wish to implement is essentially:

If it's been a while, the function will not grab focus, but operate in the background.
If the user has recently interacted, presumably he/she is interested "right now" in the results, and the function will grab focus.

Comment: Do you mean any kind of interaction with Matlab desktop or a call to a specific function several time ?

Comment: I want to know the last time the user typed in the editor, and the last time the user entered text on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tough one ! Here is a proposition to do what you want with the  command window only, based on this [undocumented code](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/setprompt-setting-matlab-desktop-prompt) and [persitent variables](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html).

I used two functions: `CW_listen` and `CW_callback`. A call to `CW_listen` (or `CW_listen(true)`) starts to listen to the command window, while a call to `CW_listen(false)` stops listening. While listening is on, any action performed on the command window trigs a call to`CW_callback`.

Here are the two functions:

```
function CW_listen(b)

% Default value
if ~exist('b', 'var'), b = true; end

% Get the reference handle to the Command Window text area
jDesktop = com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance;
try
  cmdWin = jDesktop.getClient('Command Window');
  jTextArea = cmdWin.getComponent(0).getViewport.getComponent(0);
catch
  commandwindow;
  jTextArea = jDesktop.getMainFrame.getFocusOwner;
end

% Instrument the text area's callback
if b
    set(jTextArea,'CaretUpdateCallback',@CW_callback);
else
    set(jTextArea,'CaretUpdateCallback',[]);
end
```

and

```
function CW_callback(varargin)

% Define a persistent variable
persistent last_call;

if isempty(last_call)
    last_call = clock;
else
    ts = clock;
    Dt = etime(ts, last_call);

    % Update the status bar
    dt = javaMethod('getInstance', 'com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop');
    if dt.hasMainFrame
        dt.setStatusText(['Ellapsed time: ' num2str(Dt) 's']);
    end

    if Dt>5
       fprintf('So long !\n');
       last_call = ts;   
    else
       % Do nothing
    end

end
```

I also dislayed the ellapsed time in the status bar, it was useful for developping the code and adds a quite cool feature.

You can replace the time in seconds (here 5s) and the `fprintf('So long !\n');` by any action of your choice. Be aware that inserting any kind of display outside of this `if` statement will result in an infinite display loop ...

For the moment I don't see how one could transpose this to the editor, but if you search in [Undocumented Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/) you may find how to do it ;)

Comment: Oh my, that is impressive digging.